# Generate wildcard HTTPS certificates with certbot

Tags: nginx, devops, lets-encrypt

How do I generate wildcard HTTPS certificates?

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.domain.com www.subdomain.domain.com *.subdomain.domain.com  ~^(.*)\.subdomain\.domain\.com$;
}
```

Currently, for normal domains, I generate certificates like this:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com
```

Comment: I am not sure how exactly to modify your command to reformulate it as a correct answer, so I'll just comment, but recently I followed this tutorial and worked like a charm https://medium.com/@saurabh6790/generate-wildcard-ssl-certificate-using-lets-encrypt-certbot-273e432794d7

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#does-let-s-encrypt-issue-wildcard-certificates

Answer (score 1):

For wildcard just add another entry with `*`

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d *.example.com -d example.com
```

You can further refer here [Let's Encrypt: Wildcard Certificate With Certbot](https://dev.to/nabbisen/let-s-encrypt-wildcard-certificate-with-certbot-plo)

Comment: This comment will work ( IE return without an error ) but it will not issue a wildcard certificate. Instead, if you were to have say :

server_name example.com test.example.com test2.example.com

It will make it so it's just doing those three and saving you time from having to write them all out separately, it will not however do a true wildcard allowing you to proactively have SSL on test3.example.com etc. DNS is required for that.

Answer (score 1):

I used following to generate wildcard certificate and it worked like charm. Here we are doing dns challenge hence you should have access to your dns to make entries that will be read while create certificate.

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual   -d *.example.com   -d example.com \ 
--email admin@example.com   --agree-tos \ 
--preferred-challenges dns-01 \ 
--server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

Hope this information will help you

Answer (score 0):

with your command you are issuing a Certificate via HTTP-Challenge. Let's Encrypt doesn't support issuing Wildcard-Certificates via HTTP-Challenge.

Here is a link about challenge types supported by Let's Encrypt:
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/

For Wildcard-certs you need to issue the Certs via DNS-Challenge. Therefore you need API-Access to your hosting provider or dynamic dns provider. Certbot offeres some Plugins for some of them, here is a link to the Certbot-DNS-Plugins-Site: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#dns-plugins

If your provider isn't listed you can't issue Wildcard-Certs with Certbot. There are some other tools which supports DNS-Challenges for Let's Encrypt like acme.sh, here is a link to the Github-Repository: https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh

I hope I could help you with this information.

Bananenkönig